# How do I match a Column that has a Value with a Column that has a range when ranges have multiple steps

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have two columns.
One has a numeric value and another has a range.

I need to match the value from the first column to the range on the second column and return a `true` or `false` in a third column.

I'm assuming I'd need to use the `IFS` function, but not entirely sure how.

The ranges column has the following ranges:
`1-15, 15-30, 30-50, 50+`

The value column would just have a number.

I've tried messing around with the `IFS` function:

```
=IFS((D2<=15, e2="1-15", true, false), (d2<=30, e2="15-30", true, false), (d2<=50, e2="30-50", true, false))
```

Basically, I want it to be:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
1        1-15     TRUE
16       1-15     FALSE
54       30-50    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though you might as well split the end points of the ranges:

```
=and(A2>=1*left(B2,find("-",B2)-1),A2<=1*mid(B2,find("-",B2)+1,len(B2)))
```

Assuming `1` is in A2,

Comment: `Error
In FIND evaluation, cannot find '-' within '50+'.`

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A),
 IF((A1:A >= 1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B, "\d+")))*
 (IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(B1:B, "\+$")), A1:A < 999^99,
     A1:A <  1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B, "-(\d+)")))), TRUE), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I actually have the columns in D and E. Replaced A with D and B with E, but am getting True as False and vice versa

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D1:D),
 IF((D1:D >= 1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E1:E, "\d+")))*
 (IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(E1:E, "\+$")), D1:D < 999^99,
     D1:D <  1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E1:E, "-(\d+)")))), TRUE), ))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAcGv.png

Comment: Yup, that's what I did. False is True and True is False.

Comment: make sure that formatting of **E** column is `Text` not `Date`

Comment: This is what I'm getting now: https://imgur.com/j5Tqwsk .
`1` returns FALSE for `1-15` range.

Comment: you have it shifted by 1 row, you need to change all D1 and E1 to D2 and E2

Comment: thats the valid result. what results do you expect?

Comment: `15` is FALSE when compared to the `1-15` range. I was expecting it to be TRUE. Thank you for helping me with this btw. Much appreciated!

Comment: then use this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D2:D),
 IF((D2:D >= 1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, "\d+")))*
 (IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(E2:E, "\+$")), D2:D < 999^99,
     D2:D <=  1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, "-(\d+)")))), TRUE), ))` but note that its kinda double true coz you have 15 twice in 1-15 and 15-30 eg. twice the TRUE

Comment: That's fine. Thank you!